# Symfony2 redirect from old url to new url

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I am using Symfony 2.8 and I've created a section (on the Admin Bundle) to register old paths and the new paths where to redirect when accessing the first ones. For example: My domain is `www.mypage.com`. My old webpage "About us" route was: `www.mypage.com/about`. My new webpage "About us" route is: `www.mypage.com/about-us`. So, I registered on the admin redirections section the old path and the new path this way: `/about` (old one) and `/about-us` (new one).

My question is: Where and how to compare the path, because my controller has to recognize the old path on my database and redirect to the new one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can use the eventlistener of symfony2.

Referer to : [declare a eventlistener](https://github.com/adashbob/ecommerce/blob/master/src/Ecommerce/FrontBundle/Resources/config/services/listeners_services.yml)

[EventListener's Class](https://github.com/adashbob/ecommerce/blob/master/src/Ecommerce/FrontBundle/EventListener/RedirectionListener.php)

Comment: Thx a lot adashbob, it helped me. I got it.